# Inner join with WHERE clause affecting second join

Tags: sql, syntax-error, inner-join, where-clause

I have this query and the top inner join works fine but when i add the second join i receive incorrect syntax near 'INNER' anyone any idea why?

```
SELECT  Time_ID,
    Site_Type_ID,
    SUM (staging.dbo.incoming_measure.ring_time) AS Ring_Time,
    SUM (staging.dbo.incoming_measure.hold_time) As Hold_Time,
    SUM (staging.dbo.incoming_measure.talk_time) AS Talk_Time,
    SUM (staging.dbo.incoming_measure.acw_time) AS ACW_Time
FROM staging.dbo.incoming_measure
      INNER JOIN
   (SELECT Time_ID FROM datamartend.dbo.Time_Dim ) TimeID
      ON TimeID.Time_ID = incoming_measure.StartTime

      INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Site_Type_ID, Site_Type_Code FROM datamartend.dbo.Site_Type_dim) SiteID
      ON SiteID.Site_Type_ID = incoming_measure.DBID

WHERE StartTimeDate BETWEEN StartTimeDate AND EndTimeDate  
   AND
WHERE SiteId.Site_type_code = incoming_measure.DBID

GROUP BY time_id, site_type_id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to move your `WHERE` down above the `GROUP BY`:

```
WHERE StartTimeDate BETWEEN StartTimeDate AND EndTimeDate
AND SiteId.Site_type_code = incoming_measure.DBID

Group by time_id, site_type_id
```

Comment: So I will have 4 inner joins in total each with a WHERE clause and your suggesting to put all the WHERE clauses at the bottom?

Comment: @RichardC - I only see 2 inner joins in your query above. You only can have one `WHERE` clause.  But yes, the `WHERE` goes after all of your joins.

Comment: Sorry I will be wanting a where clause in each of the separate inner quires is this possible? I've edit the code above

Comment: @RichardC - in your case you have to combine each of the clauses using an `AND`.  See my update.

Comment: Hi yeah ive updated the code again to what you've suggested but now im getting a syntax error on the second WHERE clause?

Comment: @RichardC - you have to remove the 2nd `WHERE`. see my answer.

Comment: @RichardC Just remove the second `WHERE` - and for what its worth SO is not an appropriate place to learn where all the parts of a query should go.  There is documentation for that.

Comment: Oh yeah bit of a silly mistake that not sure how i didn't spot it, thanks for the help tho